# how would I use a created app anywhere?

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on a React Native application for android but I have run into the problem of finding out how to run this app without connecting to my local host. The only thing I have been able to find is Exponent. This won't work for me because I can't  tell people "Go download Exponent on the play store and put in this complex URL un the search bar". if anyone has found any solution the help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this:

[Generating Signed APK](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

You can generate an APK and distribute it via Google Play or simply just email it to whoever you want. That way you won't need to have the react-native development server running anywhere to download the JS Bundle.